# The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called

Tags: android, admob

I already checked the other questions on StackOverflow but my situation doesn't match any of them.  I already set the unit size and unit ID, and only call build once.  What is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/topAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/topAdUnitID">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my ad create function

```
public class TopAd  extends Fragment {
    private AdView topAdView;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

        // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
        // values/strings.xml.
        topAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.topAdView);
        topAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        topAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

When I run, the app crash with the error "The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called" on the line "topAdView.loadAd(adRequest);".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have a look this one helpful for u https://github.com/ErNaveen/Admob_Banner_Xml

Comment: ads are not loading ?

Comment: It's throwing the error I used as question title and crashing the app.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I checked out your example, the only difference I can find is that you are doing the loadAd in the main Activity while I am loading it in a Fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give size of ad in xml instead of Code, 
for e.g.

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

and delete this line

```
topAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
```

Hope it Helps.

Cheers
-Aman